# Class inside a namespace

Tags: javascript

I'd like my code to look something like this, but I don't know how to make that happen.

```
var employee = namespace.employee(2); // return object
var employeeName = namespace.employee(2).name; // return string
var name = employee.name;
```

I was thinking of creating a namespace like this

```
var namespace = (function(){

})();
```

And then putting like classes inside it, I just don't quite know where to start.

Comment: Are you searching for something like this? https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to implement that behaviour:

```
var namespace = {};

namespace.employee = function (num) {
    return { name: num };
};
```

The function `employee` on the object `namespace` which returns an object containing the key `name`.

Assuming you want something like a repository of employees and the `num` tells it which employee to return:

```
var namespace = {};

var employees = [{ name: 'Joe' }, ...];

namespace.employee = function (num) {
    return employees[num];
};
```

Assuming you want the `employees` repository to not be globally accessible:

```
var namespace = {};

namespace.employee = (function () {
    var employees = [{ name: 'Joe' }, ...];

    return function (num) {
        return employees[num];
    };
})();
```